# questions for mobile android and ios system related to geographic data

Tags: discussion, scope

Many questions like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/how-to-use-osm-xml-extracts-can-i-make-an-offline-app-in-android-using-osm) are arising, tagged mobile and android, which are related to geographic data but not specifically to GIS.

Should these questions be allowed here, or be migrated to android, iOS or other sites?

Comment: do you have example questions? Some are specific to GIS some can be more to do with the location accuracy etc.

Comment: updated question

Comment: The question is relevant to GIS-SE. It can be hard to have knowledge on both data/operating system and integration.

Comment: Technically this is not a GIS-SE question but is related to a process that is. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69766/scheduled-task-calling-python-through-bat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Mapperz that such questions on how to find and use spatial data for GIS on Android and iOS mobile devices are **on-topic** for GIS-SE, and that "it can be hard to have knowledge on both data/operating system and integration".